# Clicking an element of duplicate tabs. Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing and extension that clicks a specific element on a page on some Interval/timer. There is a startButton in the popup.html that starts the interval and after X seconds it clicks the element and restarts the timer.

The function below is ran when the startButton is clicked as well as when the timer elapses.

```
content.js
function clickImage() {
  const targetElement = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
  if (targetElement) {
    targetElement.click();
    return;
  }
}
```

where the `targetSelector` is that of the image I want it to click.

The problem I am having is duplicate tabs of the same URL. tabA and tabB. If the extension active and running in tabA I want the user to be able to click the startButton from tabB and it immediately click the Element of tabB and start the timer for tabB.

What is happening is that TabA has the extension currently running and it receives the Click. When the timer elapses it does appropriately click the element in tabB.

How can I have the extension appropriately click the element in the Active Tab or tabB in the above example?

I have messed around with this function and googled/looked at the documentation but cannot find an answer to my specific question.

```
content.js
function clickImage() {
  const targetElement = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
  if (targetElement) {
    targetElement.click();
    return;
  }
}
```

```
manifest.json
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["{Specific URL}"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Show how you run the content script i.e. either content_scripts in manifest.json or executeScript.

Comment: It is in the manifest.json file. 

 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["{Specific URL}"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }

Comment: You mention popup, is that the extension popup?   Where does the start button reside?   The timer?   How does the popup script communicate with the content script?

Comment: It is the extension popup. The start button resides within the HTML of the popup. the popup communicates with the bakcground.js file which then sends messages to the content.js. The timer resides in an Offscreen.js file that sends a message to the background.js in turn the background.js send a "tick" message to the content.js which counts down from the designated interval and performs logic based on this timer.

Comment: You can use chrome.tabs.query({url: '....'}) to find all tabs, then use chrome.tabs.sendMessage with the tab's id.

Comment: So I have the tab's ID. before the "click' Happens, this in the content.js `if (message.action === "Start") {
      remainingSeconds = intervalDuration;
      updateBadge(remainingSeconds);
      getTabID();
      clickImage();
    };`  but again it "clicks" the element in tab that the extension is running in instead of the new tab.